# iOS Combine: get a strongly typed error from URLSession's dataTaskPublisher

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm struggling to form a strongly-typed error object (the `ApiErrorResponse` object in my example below)  from URLSession's `.dataTaskPublisher(for:)` publisher, but couldn't find a clue for that. Here I'm creating a class that fetches a joke object from a remote API and then I handle the result and error as follows (the class can be compiled as is in Xcode Playgrounds):

```
class DadJokes {
        
        struct Joke: Codable {
            let id: String
            let joke: String
        }
        
        enum Error: Swift.Error {
            case network
            case parsing(apiResponse: ApiErrorResponse)
            case unknown(urlResponse: URLResponse)
        }
        
        struct ApiErrorResponse: Codable {
            let code: Int
            let message: String
        }
        
    func getJoke(id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Joke, Error> {
            let url = URL(string: "https://myJokes.com/\(id)")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Accept": "application/json"]
            return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: Joke.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .mapError { error -> DadJokes.Error in
                    switch error {
                    case is DecodingError:
                        //(1) <--- here I want to get the URLResponse.data from the upstream dataTaskPublisher to decode an object of type ApiErrorResponse (which is returned by the remote API) and pass it to the parsing error case
                        return .parsing(apiResponse: ApiErrorResponse(code: 1, message: "test"))
                    case is URLError:
                        return .network
                    default:
                        //(2) <---- here I want to get the URLResponse object that is emitted from the upstream  dataTaskPublisher and pass it to the .unknown error case
                        // I need the URLResponse to read the underlying error info for debugging purposes
                        return .unknown(urlResponse: URLResponse())
                    }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
```

I have three questions, two of them are commented in the code above. The third one is: what should I do in order to return a never failing publisher from `getJoke` function ? i.e. I need the return type of the function to be `AnyPublisher<Result<Joke, Error>, Never>`

Answer (score 2):

First, I suggest a slight modification to the error enum to add URLError to the `.network` case. Otherwise you can't log information about network-level errors. (But this doesn't really impact the rest of the answer.)

```
enum Error: Swift.Error {
    case network(URLError)
    case parsing(apiResponse: ApiErrorResponse)
    case unknown(URLResponse)
}
```

To the core issue, if you want the URLResponse, then you can't throw it away so quickly by calling `.map(\.data)`. You need to keep it until you decide whether you need it.

You also need to consider cases like if the data from the API doesn't decode to either Joke or ApiErrorResponse. That's possible, and you have to deal with it.

Since this getting a little complex, it's better to leave behind the basic `.decode` and just handle the cases directly in your own `.map`:

```
    return URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .map { (data, response) -> Result<Joke, Error> in
            // Either decode a Joke
            if let joke = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Joke.self, from: data) {
                return .success(joke)
            }

            // or if that fails, try to decode an error
            else if let apiResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ApiErrorResponse.self, from: data) {
                return .failure(.parsing(apiResponse: apiResponse))
            }

            // Wasn't either of those; return the whole response
            else {
                return .failure(.unknown(response))
            }
        }
        .catch { Just(.failure(.network($0))) } // And also catch errors from dataTaskPublisher
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: that's interesting, I'm thinking of how to combine-fy the code inside the map operator and clean those if.else statements, that may get more complex as you said in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to map the success value to a success result, and then catch the error and make it a success of the Result.failure type. Like this:

```
func getJoke(id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Result<Joke, Error>, Never> {
    let url = URL(string: "https://myJokes.com/\(id)")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Accept": "application/json"]
    return URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: Joke.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .map { .success($0) }
        .catch { (error) -> AnyPublisher<Result<Joke, Error>, Never> in
            switch error {
            case is DecodingError:
                return Just(.failure(.parsing(apiResponse: ApiErrorResponse(code: 1, message: "test")))).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            case is URLError:
                return Just(.failure(.network)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            default:
                return Just(.failure(.unknown(urlResponse: URLResponse()))).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer of the 3rd question, but I'm still stuck at how to decode the ApiErrorResponse object from the data value that is emitted by the  upstream publisher (dataTaskPublisher) - (questions 1 & 2 which are commented inside the code)

Comment: That depends on the internals of the data the server returns.

Comment: The server returns a json error that doesn't change in all cases: `{"code": 10, "message": "some error message"}` which's supposed to be decoded from the data emitted by the dataTaskPublisher

Comment: Are you saying that the server returns either a joke or an error? Are the two structures completely different or are they both wrapped up in a single object?

Comment: yes exactly, the server returns either a joke or an error struct, just one of them for any given request, they are not wrapped inside a single object.